# UNIX: cat large number of files - output being doubled

Tags: unix

I need to concatenate a large number of text files from a series of directories. All the text files have the same name but some folders do not contain the file and just need to be skipped.

When I use `cat ./**/File.txt > newFile.txt` I get the following error `/bin/cat: Argument list too long`.

I tried using the `ulimit` command a few different ways but that did not work.

I have tried:

```
find . -name File.txt -exec cat {} \; > newFile.txt
find . -name File.txt -exec cat {} \+ > newFile.txt
find . -type f -name File.txt | xargs cat
```

and this results in the files being concatenated twice. For example, I have 3 text files named File.txt, each in a different directory, each with a different line of text:

> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3

When I do the above commands my newFile.txt looks like:

> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3
>
> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3

I can't figure out why this is happening twice. When I use the command `cat ./**/File.txt > newFile.txt` on my small test set, it works fine and I end up with one file that has:

> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3

I also tried

```
for a in File.txt ; do cat $a >> newFile.txt ; done
```

but get the message

```
cat: File.txt: No such file or directory
```

because some of the directories do not contain this text file, is  my guess.

Is there another way to do this, or is there a reason my files are being concatenated twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it

```
find . -name File.txt -exec cat {} >> output.txt \;
```

This searches for all occurrences of the file `File.txt` and *appends* the cat'ed output of that file to the file `output.txt`

However, I have tried your find command and it too also works.

```
find . -name File.txt -exec cat {} \; > newFile.txt
```

I would suggest that you clear down the output file `newFile.txt` before you try either your find or my find as follows:

```
 >newFile.txt
```

This is a handy way to empty a file's contents. (Although this should not matter to you right now emptying a file by redirecting nothing to it can be done even if another process is writing to the file)

Hope this helps.